# Data Tables set selection on page load

Tags: jquery, datatables

Selection is made by use of a check box. When the check box is clicked the row is selected:

```
    select: {
        style: 'multi',
        selector: ':checkbox'
    }
```

I want to save the selected rows to a database, I do this by use of the ID of the checkboxes checked. When I load the page with checkboxes ticked, I set class of ticked checkboxes to selected:

```
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $row.addClass('selected');
    });
```

When the page is loaded dataTables does not acknowledge it as selected other than aesthetically. The row is highlighted but when I try to use functions such as the download to excel button, which only downloads selected rows, it does not find any selected rows to download. As if I have only applied the CSS style and not the appropriate functions behind it. When I uncheck a checkbox which was loaded checked, the row does not return to an unselected state, it remains highlighted as if I had just selected it.

```
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Download Excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                }
            }
```

**How can I load the page with checkboxes ticked and have dataTables recognise it as selected other than aesthetically?**

to recreate:
Click any tickbox to select row, download excel - works
Click button to reload - it reloads with row selected, click download excel, nothing is downloaded.
Untick row highlighted, it does not recognise as unselect.

https://jsfiddle.net/mbgfwjh2/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I missed the [select()](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/integrationhttp://) function. Simply retrieve the row of the check box and call select() against it:

```
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');           
        table.row($row).select();
    });
```